# How do I fix this regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the string:

```
CN=Help & Technical,CN=Users,DC=dave,DC=com
```

And I want to strip out everything between the '=' and the ',' in a set of groups. Basically Im using this...

```
=([\w-\s]*)
```

And it is only dragging back the following :

```
=help
=users
=dave
```

So you can see im not getting Help & Technical in the first group which is what I want. Is this possible can anybody help me with the regex I just cant work it out...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but `=([^,]*)` should work.

Comment: this works great and also works when other characters are put in

Answer (score 2):

You just need to include the `&` sign in your regular expression here.

```
=([\w-\s&]*)
```

Note that this is pretty restrictive so far... no apostrophes, no numbers, and no other punctuation. You may want to consider whether any of that will show up and add them as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
=(.+),|\w
```

It should match everything after the = until a , or a enter